# Curiously, why does my abs-function return -0?

Tags: objective-c, c

The following abs-function sometimes returns `-0`  (minus zero)

```
inline float abs(float a){
    return( a>=0.0f? a :-a);
}
```

To be more specific, the statement  `sprintf(str, "%.2f", abs(-0.00f) );` produces "-0.00", and that is annoying since the string is displayed to the user.

Question:

1) Why does it produce `-0`?

2) How to fix it?

PS: I am using xcode's (objective) c compiler.

Comment: Just curious.. any reason you're not using `fabs` and `fabsf`?

Comment: @JamesWebster Okay, fabs would fix the problem!  But how is fabs implemented, and what is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: @ragnarius it should output: `-0.00`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, that is correct! sprintf produces -0.00 (It was shown as -0 in the debugger)

Comment: Change it to *return( a>0.0f? a :-a);*

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: No, if a==0 one should not return -a

Comment: `float my_abs(float a)` can be implemented like: `return (a ? (a>0 ? a : -a) : 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. -0 is an artifact of binary representation, 0 with the sign bit set. Wikipedia has [a comprehensive article on signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) if you would like further details.
2. Use fabs() as people have said above. If you really really really want to inline, chain your compares:

   inline float abs(float a)
   {
       return (a > 0.f) ? a : ( (a < 0.f) ? -a : 0);
   }

Answer (score 12):

1. Because `-0.0 == 0.0` and thus `-0.0 >= 0.0` is true.
2. Use `fabs` (or `fabsf` for float instead of `double`) rather than trying to reinvent it.

Comment: It's interesting how `printf` determines when to output the `-` sign. Surely it doesn't compare with zero since -0.0 is not less than 0.0.

Comment: To me it is not obvious that -0.0 == 0.0. The binary representations of -0.0 and 0.0 are different, and I would have guessed that two floats are equal if and only if their binary representations are equal (but then I would have guessed wrong, at least for some compilers)

Comment: @ragnarius: It's not really a compiler issue, but it's part of the IEEE 754 standard.  Most implementations are at least nominally IEEE 754 compliant, and those that aren't often still support `-0.0`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Okey, thank you! I knew the standard told us how to store floats, does it also tell us how to compare them? Is -0 == -1.0f/Inf ? And, if so, is 1.0/Inf == -1.0/Inf?

Comment: @ragnarius: `1.0/Inf == 0.0 == -0.0 == -1.0/Inf` — remember, using `==`, `-0.0 == +0.0`.  However, `1.0/Inf` will generate a positive number and `-1.0/Inf` will generate a negative number.  The sign of the output is determined only by the signs of the inputs, as long as the output isn't `NaN`: positive divided by positive is positive, negative divided by positive is negative.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, R.. : hey! please check my answer, Is it correct way to shows that bit represents of `-0.0 != 0.0` **?**  Thanks!

Comment: @Inspired The minus sign is the **easiest** character to generate in the decimal representation of a binary floating-point number. The (comparatively tricky) conversion requires accessing the bits of the representation anyway.

Comment: @Pascal: Accessing the representation is not necessary to `printf`. It's possible with pure IEEE arithmetic.

Comment: @R.. I almost asked this as a SO question, but realized it was going to be one of these “do X without using the obvious best tool for the job, Y” job-interview-like questions that I so hate. Do you mean “IEEE arithmetic” like “using `frexp()`, multiplications by power of two and truncation to integer in a way that essentially extracts the representation”, or something less obvious?

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq Sample -0.0, 0.0 mathematical differentiator: `printf("%e %e\n", atan2( 0.0, -1), atan2(-0.0, -1));`

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I wouldn't call it "extracting the representation", at least not in the C sense of "representation", since no type-punning or similar is involved. It's just a matter of extracting the value in mantissa/exponent form. This can be done with `frexp`, but if you call that inspecting the representation, you can achieve the same with plain arithmetic, albeit slightly slower.

Comment: Completely off-topic now, but I believe that Brisebarre and Muller's algorithm for multiplying a floating-point number by an arbitrary constant C can be used to convert to decimal without ever using integer arithmetic (section 5.5 in the Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic, with C the appropriate power of 10 e.g 10^-98 to print 1.23E100 to 2 decimal places)

Comment: @PascalCuoq: 10^-98 does not fit in any floating-point type, so I'm not sure what you have in mind. Even if it did, the result would not be representable, so this approach would, at best, only work when the number of places of precision to be printed is small. If you have other ideas, I'd be interested in hearing them. So far I have not seen any simpler approaches to floating point decimal printing than my version of it. Maybe we could move this to chat since it's getting off-topic; unfortunately I don't know how to do that until SO suggests the option to us.

Comment: Note how section 5.5 is about computing the correctly rounded to nearest value of the product of a floating-point number x by a real C. C can be 10^-98. With Brisebarre and Muller's approach, it would take two FP numbers per power of ten to represent all the constants.

Comment: It requires an FMA, and it only works for 16 or so decimal places, so all in all, it may not work for a standard library, but I do not regret taking the time to think about this. I think I will implement a single-precision proof-of-concept (one can emulate single-precision FMA with double-precision multiplication and addition).

Comment: Nice. Technically the standard library is not required to provide more than `DECIMAL_DIG` correct places, so it may be acceptable for implementing a conforming but low-quality `printf`.

Comment: I wonder though if computing 2^53 * 10^-98 is as expensive as the standard approach to exact printing...

Answer (score 2):

Use `signbit()` to differentiate.  Works with -0 and -INF and, I think, -NAN (if there is such a thing).

```
// C11
inline float ragnarius_abs(float a) {
  return signbit(a) ? -a : a;
}
```

As to why `a = -0.0f; a>=0.0f? a :-a;` produces `-0`?
`-0.0f >= 0.0f` is true: `-0.0f` and `0.0f` are both *numerically* equal, thus `a`, which is `-0.0f` is returned.

---

Further notes about floating point types:

-0 equals 0.  It is the *sole* floating point exception where 2 different binary IEEE 754 bit representations compare as equal.  Some other floating point formats have various different bit representations representing the same numeric value.

NAN does not equal NAN.  NAN may be expressed with numerous representations, but even if 2 NANs have the exact same bit representation, they will *not* numerically (==) compare as equal.

Comment: Okay! Is signbit defined in C (or only in c++11?)?

Comment: Do you think fabs() is implemented this way?

Comment: `signbit()` is C11.  C11 draft appendix F.10.4.2 says fabs(±0) returns +0.  So it is likely ragnarius_abs() is simple a re-creation of `fabs()`.  Oh well.

Comment: But fabs() is defined in C, it cannot use signbit() (?).

Comment: ( One possible implementation is  if (a==0.0f) return 0.0f; return( a>=0.0f? a :-a); )

Comment: Please elaborate why `fabs()` is insufficient for `sprintf(str, "%.2f", fabs(-0.00f) )`.   Looks like it does just what is requested.  Should you want to roll your own, `signbit()` will work or your `if (a==0.0f) ...`.  There are other approaches too with variant degrees of speed and compatibility, but further definition of your goals is needed should the preceding be deemed insufficient.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Yes, I knew that but I see my post did not reflect the correct explanation as you pointed out.  I've attempted a correction.  Thank-you.